# What's the use of the new Delphi TActivityIndicator when it runs in the main thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10-seattle, activity-indicator

I was hoping to use the new Seattle TActivityIndicator when I open a large query but this is blocking the main vcl thread and hence stopping the TActivityIndicator.

Surely the TActivityIndicator indicates activity and should work in a different thread.

Without having to put in Application.Processmessages everywhere is there another way forward?

Comment: The indicator is supposed to work in the main thread, while your task is supposed to do its job in a worker thread.

Comment: So I redesign my app to fit in with an activity indicator? I'd rather hope it would be the other way round.

Comment: That's unrealistic. You made the mistake when you put the long running task on the UI thread. No amount of magic can paper over that mistake. You have to fix it. Put the long running task on a worker. Oh, and don't call ProcessMessages ever.

Comment: Well, the GUI is what the name says, while your program activity should be designed to work as independent as possible from the GUI. The indicator is just to show something is happening, and you could use other means to do the same. But still you should not have to redesign your app if it was correct from the start.

Comment: Unrealistic to have a wait component work while the main thread is working? Why do Delphi people have such low expectations of their software provider?

Comment: We don't have low expectations. This is just how the VCL is designed. The VCL is not an outlier here. Given the design of Win32, the threading rules for VCL are a sign of good design. The original designers did a good job.

Comment: The only criticism I can think of is the fact that the VCL made it too simple to make an app GUI centric instead of separating the application logic from the GUI. This is more a question of education than flaws in the tools.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words there Dave. Now, Instead of focusing on how crap my app is that it uses the main thread to get data maybe we could focus on creating a activity indicator that works without me creating threads. Why can't the activity indicator do this?

Comment: *Why can't the activity indicator do this?* Because a thread can do only one task at a time. And so a single thread cannot service the message queue, and perform your long running task at the same time. My name is not Dave.

Comment: And I'm not calling your application "crap". You seem a little agitated. The unavoidable truth is that you should not perform long running tasks on the UI thread. That's a well known and long standing rule. It's pretty much the raison d'être for threads.

Comment: As I eluded to in my question. I understand that threads do 1 thing at a time. Hence my question was Why doesn't TActivityIndicator do it's stuff in a different thread so I can happily plonk Datasets on my form. Yes I understand best practice of using a different thread for a longer db request but most apps out there are not doing this. Maybe an option for lazy programmers like myself is for the TActivityIndicator to work outside the UI thread?

Comment: It wouldn't help you even if it could be done. Because you'd still be blocking the main thread. So your GUI would freeze, Windows would ghost your window, mark it as not responding.

Comment: I agree with @TomRobertson here, Since the purpose of the TActivityIndicator is to show that your application is busy/doing something, it should work even if the application is busy. 
I know that the whole VCL is working in the main thread AND I agree with that, but this activity indicator is special through its own purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The new VCL UI activity indicator is a progress indicator designed to mirror the Windows 10 look and feel. It is, as, any other VCL control, subject to the usual VCL threading rules. All access to the control must be from the UI thread.

So, you need to create and show the indicator from the UI thread. You need to make sure that the UI thread is not ever blocked. Which means that any long running tasks must be shipped off to worker threads in order for them not to block the UI thread.

Plus ça change, plus c'est la même chose.

Answer (score 2):

The UI can only be updated from the main thread. The activity indicator also has to obey that rule. Put your activity in a different thread instead. Then your application will remain responsive.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I was however hoping to leave the app blocked and have the user wait for the query while admiring nice twirling dots without delving into threads

Comment: You can disable your UI and display the activity indicator while your worker thread is running, then stop the indicator and unlock the UI when the worker thread is finished.  This way, the user still have to wait, but it lets the UI thread stay responsive to processing UI messages from the OS while the worker thread is busy.

Comment: from thread you could also update something in main form/thread.     `Synchronize(
     procedure
      begin
      ..........
      end
    );`